# VueJS replace video with a default placeholder on error

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm new to front end (vue). Would love to hear some feedback

I have a video playing on loop. It works fine if the url is good. But if the url is not found, I want to replace it with a placeholder (could be an image). I've tried:

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" muted loop>
    <source :src="url" type="video/mp4" @error="replaceWithPlaceholder">
</video>
```

```
replaceWithPlaceholder(e) {
    e.target.src = defaultUrl
},
```

I've done this the exact same way with an image, but Im not sure why it isnt working for a video. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is that you want some sort if-statement on the `video` element it self

Answer (score 0):

figured it out by using `poster`

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" muted loop poster="defaultUrl">
```